# How to get the shortest distance of a point from a polyline in python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-polyline

I need to find the shortest distance of a specific point `P, (lat, lng)` from a given polyline in python?

What I tried is, converting the polyline to a set of points and then from each point calculating the distance to the given point `P` and then taking the minimum of them.